# How to create makefile for Linux for the next command - gcc -shared -home/ time.c /libperi.a -o time.so

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation

How to create a makefile for Linux for the next command?

```sh
gcc -shared -home/ time.c /libperi.a -o time.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pick a name. This command appears to build `time.so`, so that's a good name.

The makefile is just a text file. Write it like this:

```
time.so:
    gcc -shared -home/ time.c /libperi.a -o time.so
```

That whitespace before the `gcc` is a TAB, not spaces.

Once you have that working, you can read [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and learn more about Make, which will allow you to write more powerful rules.

Comment: I forgot said, Thank you!